# How to control Windows by phone using bluetooth?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, remote

Is there any program that would allow me to control some basic stuff on computer by phone using bluetooth? I am using Windows 7.

Controling volume, playing next song or forwarding video would be all I need for now. Best solution would be if I could send keystrokes from the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for a **bluetooth remote control** app for your phone. Sony Ericsson phones come with such apps built-in. It has all the functionality you want. Here's one for [Windows Mobile](http://www.jaylee.org/remotecontrol/), one for [Symbian S60](http://www.devilsworkshop.org/free-symbian-s60-bluetooth-remote-control-for-windows-pc/) and a guide for [Blackberrys](http://blog.alantan.com/2008/06/using-your-blackberry-or-other.html). Most manufacturers have such apps, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone's OS is not one of those mentioned by alex, but it supports J2ME, you could try [Mobile Witch Remote Control](http://www.mobilewitch.com/Mobilewitch-Bluetooth-Remote-Control_software_details_2.htm) (freeware).

I'm using it on a Nokia 6300 to control a Windows 7 computer.